# how to do average i npython by using csv

Tags: python

```
Date,Indonesia,Japan,Malaysia,Singapore,South Korea,Thailand
15-Apr-20,282,455,170,334,27,30
16-Apr-20,297,482,85,447,22,29
17-Apr-20,380,585,110,728,22,28
18-Apr-20,407,628,69,623,18,33
19-Apr-20,325,566,54,942,8,32
20-Apr-20,327,390,84,596,13,27
21-Apr-20,185,367,36,1426,9,19
22-Apr-20,375,378,57,1111,11,15
23-Apr-20,283,276,50,1016,8,13
24-Apr-20,357,468,71,1037,6,68
25-Apr-20,436,652,88,618,10,0
26-Apr-20,396,290,51,931,10,15
27-Apr-20,275,203,38,799,10,9
28-Apr-20,214,191,40,528,14,7
29-Apr-20,415,276,31,690,9,9
30-Apr-20,260,236,94,528,4,7
```

Using this data, how can I calculate a daily average of all countries over the whole period?

Comment: maybe show us what you have tried?

Comment: i use if elif else to do it

Comment: ef dispAve():
    ave_data1 = ave_data2 = ave_data3 = ave_data4 = ave_data5 = ave_data6 = total = 0
    print('='*40)
    print('Please choose option:')
    print('A - Indonesia')
    print('B - Japan')
    print('C - Malaysia')
    print('D - Singapore')
    print('E - South Korea')
    print('F - Thailand')
    print('Q - Quit')
    print('='*40)
    sel =(input('Please input ur selection:'))
    
    if sel in ["A","a"]:
        total = total + (len(Indonesia))
        ave_data1 = total/len(Indonesia)
        print('The average daily data in Indonesia is {ave_data1}')

Comment: something like that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got this in a CSV file, it's fairly straightforward with the `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
print(df.mean())

Indonesia      325.8750
Japan          402.6875
Malaysia        70.5000
Singapore      772.1250
South Korea     12.5625
Thailand        21.3125
dtype: float64
```

Comment: tq for helping me

Comment: i can use it in def function ??

Comment: Yes, you could put it in a function.

Comment: you can see panda as excel type where it has column and rows. check this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv